# Drain of kitchen sink on a 1/70 slope over 5 m - passive or active solutions

Tags: kitchens, drain

I am making a home improvement and want to route a kitchen drain of 40mm in an existing sleeve of 110mm diameter at approx. floor level  over a straight run of 5 m. The best fall I can hope to get is thus 1/70 - half of what is recommended (1/40).  I could chase / surface mount a 1/40 sloped drain, but that is impractical, structurally risky and/or takes an inordinate amount of space.
I see 2 possibilities:

1. go passive and live with the risk of blockages.  Does it make sense to provide a flushing point, where you can run clean water into the drain after each discharge to flush out what may settle?
2. collect, settle and pump - Are there standard under counter tank/separator units with pumps that can be installed under the kitchen sink?   I realize that the units have to be cleaned regularly, which is ok. However,  I am concerned about the potential of smell in the kitchen and pushback into the sink.
   I would imagine that retrofitted kitchen islands face similar issues.
   This is for a simple single bowl for a household of 2 adults.